# Remote Logging using Log4j2

Tags: sockets, log4j2

So i have this task to log activities to a file, but it has to be done 
remotely on the server side, Remote logging.

> NOTE : Remote Logging has to be in latest version of **Log4j2(2.10)**

My task was simple

1. Send logging info to a port.
2. Log info from port to a file.

My Discoveries

1. Socket Appender exist which help send info to a port. This is it, you dont need to create a client side code or anything.

**Socket appender configuration in *log4j2.properties***

```
appender.socket.type = Socket
appender.socket.name= Socket_Appender
appender.socket.host = "IP address"
appender.socket.port = 8101
appender.socket.layout.type = SerializedLayout
appender.socket.connectTimeoutMillis = 2000
appender.socket.reconnectionDelayMillis = 1000
appender.socket.protocol = TCP
```

Adapting from [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/log4j-socketappender-and-socket-server-example/). But this is also log4j 1.x adaptation.

1. I found out that before log4j 2.6 to listen to a port we used TcpSocketServer which started a server using LogEventBridge[This helped reach that conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186957/log4j2-securetcpsocketserver-setup). This class was in core.net.server which is no longer available.Assuming it is not used anymore and the only similar/closest class, TcpSocketManager.Other links that helped. [How to use SocketAppend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825917/log4j-how-does-a-socket-appender-work)
2. Then i tried this

   ```
   public static final Logger LOG=LogManager.getLogger(myapp.class.getName());

   main(){
   LOG.debug("DEBUG LEVEL");
   }
   ```

and got the following error

> main ERROR TcpSocketManager (TCP:IPAddress:8111) caught exception 
>   and will continue: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I know this work because i made it read to a socket but there was no one listening, but somehow i messed up big time and there was a code change.

I need help how to go ahead. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket server to remotely receive log events has been moved to a separate repository: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-tools

This still needs to be released.

Comment: As i specified i am doing remote logging. This is what is did.  SocketAppender and its logger will automatically send logs across using the port number. 
Next i fired up the code and got error  "_Socket Not Available Error_". So i created a socket make it listen to that port number, using ServerSocket.

All good now its sending logs across. 

>But now how do i output that event logs received via socketappender to console or file using via the same properties file on the receiving end?

Comment: You can check out the above logging-log4j-tools project and build it with `mvn clean install`. This will generate a binary (jar) containing a socket server that can output the received log events into a log file.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Nexus is not able to get this dependency. Do we need to build this project locally and push it to the nexus?

Comment: Yes please. Also please let the log4j dev community know with a jira ticket or email to logging-users.